# Installing matching kernel-headers

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I am trying to install kernal-headers for the kernel `6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64` on fedora, but `dnf` only gives me these options:

```
    Name         : kernel-headers
    Version      : 6.3.3
    Release      : 100.fc37
    Architecture : x86_64
    Size         : 5.9 M
    Source       : kernel-headers-6.3.3-100.fc37.src.rpm
    Repository   : @System
    From repo    : updates
    Summary      : Header files for the Linux kernel for use by glibc
    URL          : http://www.kernel.org/
```

```
    Available Packages
    Name         : kernel-headers
    Version      : 6.0.5
    Release      : 300.fc37
    Architecture : i686
    Size         : 1.5 M
    Source       : kernel-headers-6.0.5-300.fc37.src.rpm
    Repository   : fedora
    Summary      : Header files for the Linux kernel for use by glibc
```

How and where would I get the matching ones

Reason:
I am trying to install Nvidia drivers, but they fail, so I thought that not matching kernel-headers could be the problem. I am using the kernel `6.0.7-301.fc37.x86_64`, because on Nvidias website, this is the latest supported kernel on Fedora 37.

Comment: How did you install your kernel? And: the usual rpmfusion installation route for the Nvidia drivers should automatically depends on the right headers.

Comment: I actually never installed a kernel myself, the 6.0.7 version was available in my grub so I guess I once installed it via an update. I have tried installing the Nvidia drivers this way, but I think the card that I am trying to install is a legacy one and so I took the installer from here https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/182244/en-us/

Comment: Don't go the "native" nvidia route if you can use the legacy rpmfusion drivers, https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryHowto%5Cb%29#Determining_your_card_model

Comment: This is why I went with the `Data Center Driver for Linux x64 Version:     460.106.00`. But when I run the installer, it errors and I thought the problem could be, that my kernel-headers are not the same as my kernel. I could open a separate question for the whole installation, but I would only do this as a last resort and currently I am trying to get the ‘kernel-source', 'kernel-devel’ and the 'kernel-headers' in sync with the rest of the distro.